# why can not import MediaPlayer in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

it's strange that I import MediaPlayer in my swift file, but when I press cmd and click Mediaplayer, it got nothing .

and I write the code as follows:

```
import MediaPlayer
var audioPlayer:MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController()
```

but it warns me " Use of undeclared type 'MPMoviePlayerController'"

why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Go to target settings ->build phases->link binary with libraries->add MediaPlayer.framework

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have linked the MediaPlayer Framework to your project first.